# Rails 4 Auditing Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, audit-logging

I'm looking for a Rails 4 supported gem that does auditing related tasks. Similar gems I found, but are not supporting Rails 4 (except for paper-trail, but it has all of that versioning stuff that I don't need):

[github audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited)

[github pfeed](https://github.com/parolkar/pfeed)

[github userstamp](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp)

[github paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Does anyone have any recommendations? Audited gem seems to be the most similar to what I'm looking for.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem, even without being designed for auditing, you can use it to track user actions.

You have one screencast on the subject [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) and it supports both Rails 3.x and 4.x.

Answer (score 13):

I just found this gem:  https://github.com/continuum/espinita

This is from their readme:

> Audit activerecord models like a boss. Tested in rails 4 and ruby
>   2.0.0.
>
> This project is heavily based in audited gem.

Comment: This gem has not been updated in 7 months, and the documentation is something to be desired.  I would stick with Audited.

Answer (score 4):

Came across [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) which seems to be an auditing library which is under [active](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/graphs/contributors) development.

After some evaluation I chose this library for one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mongoid with MongoDB, try [mongoid-audit](https://github.com/rs-pro/mongoid-audit). It's a wrapper around [mongoid-history](https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history) which can also be used directly. From mongoid-audit readme:

> Since 1.0.0, mongoid_audit is no longer a fork, but a wrapper of mongoid-history, providing out-of-the-box Userstamp, RailsAdmin integration and easier setup and configuration.